# Position Element to break through divs

Tags: css, html, positioning, css-position

So I have a case of client-itus here. The client is whining and my boss is demanding that I add a logo [image: Scolari Engineering] underneath the Archives tab over the banner ad seen, which would break through the structure I've set up. We're two days from launch and I have a choice of either taking precious time away from other work to restructure the layout, or find a way to position that logo without having to futz with the divs. I understand HTML and basic CSS, so I thought I'd see if I could find a better solution before going about this the hard way. Thank you for all your help! The current page can be seen at [ctdailydose.com/new](http://ctdailydose.com/new)

(Just for clarity, what I want to do is add big circular logo on the right that says "Scolari Engineering" without having to rewrite the CSS and change the header's entire structure.)

Comment: looks easy enough to do... but where in the HTML should the round logo go?  should it be clickable like the link?  Also, do you have the logo already made? linking the logo would help a lot.

Comment: Yes the logo should be clickable like the link, since it will be overlaid over the banner ad like it was a part of it. And here's the logo uploaded (I have not resized it yet though, it will be 100x100 in the page.) http://coffeetalk.com/DD/Scolari_logo.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add your image (logo) at the end of the end of the achor in your menu-banner div and position:absolute right:0px top:0px for it in your css. Adjust the position as needed.

Comment: It causes problems if the page is resized though.

Comment: @vdbuilder gah! no no no... just give a parent element (e.g. menu-banner) position:relative and the actual image position:absolute... position fixed is definitely not a good way to go. D:

Comment: @Joseph Why? He asked for a way to do this "without having to futz with the divs".

Comment: @Joseph Getting there! Used your suggestion and now the logo is behaving how I'd like it to, but it's currently sitting underneath the banner. Should I wrap it in another div to position it properly?

Comment: @vdbuilder Because it's a bad way to do it.  It's probably the least maintainable way to do it,  It will also experience problems with scrolling (it'll stay in that one spot all the time even over text).  You had it right the first time.  The reason why it was having issues with resizing is because it was treating the window as the parent.  If you just simply make menu-banner position:relative, you can still use position:absolute. That's the only problem with your first concept in your answer. Also, using position:absolute changes no divs in the HTML.  You just have to add a style rule to one.

Comment: @Justin just look at my answer below. :P  It's already been tested and works just like your mockup.

Comment: Oh! and one last thing.  The logo should be in the anchor tag like the other image; not at the end of the document.

Comment: Glad I could help (with Joseph helping me).